# React JS: Loop through a multi-dimensional array and determine/load the correct component

Tags: reactjs, multidimensional-array

Using [React](https://facebook.github.io/react/), I'm fetching data from an API, [a sample of which can be seen here](http://d.pr/f/13h8f/myR2jpyO).

I need to loop through the `body` section (multi-dimensional array) and then determine what type of 'block' it is:

- heading
- text
- quote
- frameImgeBlock
- quoteImageBlock
- frameQuoteBlock

Depending which block type it is then I need to create/load the corresponding React component (as I'm imagining it's better to separate these into individual React components).

How is it best to approach this in React/JS?

I may be able to tweak the API output a little if someone can suggest an easier approach there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a "translation" function like so, which would call external components:

```
// Import external deps

import Heading from './src/heading';

// Later in your component code

function firstKey(obj) {
  return Object.keys(obj)[0];
}

getDomItem(item) {
  const key = firstKey(item);
  const val = item[val];
  switch (key) {
    case "heading":
      return <Heading heading={ val.heading } ...etc... />
    case "other key..."
      return <OtherElm ...props... />
  }
}

render() {
  // data is your object 
  return data.content.body.map(item => 
    this.getDomItem(item[firstKey(item)])
  );
}
```

Comment: Ah, I see. That was just what I was after but just not sure how to express it. :) It's coming up with `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'heading' of undefined` for `{ val.heading }` `val` returns `undefined`. Any ideas?

Comment: Well, this was just a draft code to illustrate the main idea, not surprised it does not work out of the box and needs some debugging from you :) (I had a quick look but I dont see what's wrong right away)

Comment: Yeah I've made a few changes and for the most part it's working. I just really need to figure out how to pass the properties of the 'block' object through as props to the block compoment. Here's what I have currently: http://d.pr/f/QSVM/3bNvWbWp

Comment: You can do it manually by calling relevant props from the current item (like for the `<Heading ...` above), or you can pass them all, as is, to the component, if your js compiler supports the spread operator, like so: `<MyComponent { ...val } />` (or using the non-JSX syntax with `apply()`)

Comment: Yeah that's what I was trying and my intention but `val` and `key` are empty. http://d.pr/i/tvW6/ky1ffs9g. Just not sure how to populate `val` to pass through. I'm using Webpack with Babel so spread operator is fine otherwise.

Comment: Got it! `const val = item[key];`:) Thanks @Pandaiolo